# Not able to read value from a text file using shell script

Tags: shell

I need the value of "Name" from the output.txt file. **Please help me how can I get the value of Name from the above file using shell script.**

cat output.txt

```
OK
Found 1 object in bucket 'goldcode':

Name                            Last Modified              Object Size   
copra_ws_07_20_2021_13_47.zip   Jul 20, 2021 at 13:47:42   125.96 MiB
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `awk`:

```
awk '/Name/{getline; print $1}' output.txt
```

Output:

```
copra_ws_07_20_2021_13_47.zip
```

Answer (score 0):

Another awk solution (without using `getline`, cf. http://awk.freeshell.org/AllAboutGetline):

```
awk 'c{print $1; next} c&&!--c; /Name/{ c=1 }' output.txt
```